# Intentando hacer un etch-a-sketch

Tags: javascript, html, web

tratando de hacer el etch-a-sketch tengo un problema al agregar la opcion de poder cambiar la cantidad de "grillas" que hay:
Ejemplo del etch-a-sketch:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema empezo  por que se acumulaban, ya que se ejecuta la función `makeRows` varias veces al intentar cambiar la cantidad de cuadrados en la grilla,por que pasaba esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo solucione agregando una function donde elimine los hijos del container:

```
function deleteGrid(){
while(container.firstChild){
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
}
```

};

El problema ahora es que al estar el nuevo "grid", en este caso de 2x2:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya no tiene efecto la función encargada de pintar los cuadrados mediante hover. Esto es lo que deseo resolver.
He aquí el código:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const btnClear = document.querySelector(".clear");
const btnReset = document.querySelector(".reset");
let x = 16

//ROWS AND COLUMNS FUNCTION
function makeRows (rows, cols){
    container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
    container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);
    for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++){
        let cell = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(cell).className = "item"
    }

    
};

//Page starts with a 16x16 grid
makeRows(x,x);


//Delete grid
function deleteGrid(){
    while(container.firstChild){
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
};

//RESET BOTON
btnReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
    divs.forEach((div) => div.classList.remove("permahover"));
    deleteGrid();
    x = prompt("How many rows and columns you want?");
    makeRows(x,x);
});

//HOVER COLOR 
const divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item"));

divs.forEach((div) =>
    div.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        div.classList.add("permahover");
})); 


//CLEAR BTN
divs.forEach((div) =>
    btnClear.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
        div.classList.remove("permahover");
}));
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  height: 50rem;
  width: 50rem;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
}

.reset,
.clear {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: rgb(164, 218, 231);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.permahover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="clear">Clear</button>
            <button class="reset">Clear & Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>

    <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Creeria que el problema se encuentra , claremente, en el `addEventListener` encargado del hover, pero no se donde ya que los nuevos cuadrados tienen la clase `.item`

Answer (score 1):

La asignación del evento la realizas una sola vez al iniciar la aplicación, al asignar los eventos a los divs, al borrar estos, los eventos dejan de servir. Para evitar esto puedes asignar los eventos al crear el propio elemento (ahorrándote de paso el loop donde los asignas) o asignar el evento al contenedor y mirar el target del evento (Desconozco que es mas optimo), al ser el propio contenedor quien contiene el evento, no sera necesario volver a asignarlos.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const btnClear = document.querySelector(".clear");
const btnReset = document.querySelector(".reset");
let x = 16

//ROWS AND COLUMNS FUNCTION
function makeRows (rows, cols){
    container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
    container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);
    for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++){
        let cell = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(cell).className = "item"
        // Movemos la asignación del evento a la creación del elemento, asi siempre se creara el evento con la aparación del elemento y evitamos dar loops de más
        cell.addEventListener("mouseover", () => { cell.classList.add("permahover")});
    }
    
};

/* Tambien puedes añadir el evento al contenedor y mirar si el target es un div con la clase item
container.addEventListener("mouseover", ({ target }) => {

  if (target.classList.contains("item")) target.classList.add("permahover")

})
*/

//Page starts with a 16x16 grid
makeRows(x,x);

//Delete grid
function deleteGrid(){
    while(container.firstChild){
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
};

//RESET BOTON
btnReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (let div of container.childNodes) div.classList.remove("permahover");
    deleteGrid();
    x = prompt("How many rows and columns you want?");
    makeRows(x,x);
});

// No es necesario poner un evento por cada div, con tener un solo evento y recorrer los divs es suficiente
btnClear.addEventListener("click" , () => {

    for (let div of container.childNodes) div.classList.remove("permahover")
    
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  height: 50rem;
  width: 50rem;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.reset,
.clear {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: rgb(164, 218, 231);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.permahover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="clear">Clear</button>
            <button class="reset">Clear & Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </section>

    <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahhh genial, muchisimas gracias! Una ultima duda, donde dices " No es necesario poner un evento por cada div, con tener un solo evento y recorrer los divs es suficiente" te refieres a en vez de iterar los div y agregarle un evento a cada uno, que haga un evento y ese evento este en cada div?

Comment: Al tener un solo evento que recorre todos los divs, no te es necesario crear/eliminar los eventos para cada uno, el propio evento ya recorre todos los divs existentes.